# ggplot: dotplot with column index on y-axis and its value as dot size VS a second column value on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data table that looks like this

```
#       A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
#   1:  1   1   3   1   5   5
#   2:  2   1   3   2   6   9
#   3:  3   2   1   3   8   11
#   4:  4   2   1   4   9   15
```

Now I would like to use ggplot to plot on the x-axis the values of column B1, B2 and B3, using the corresponding value in column A1, A2 and A3 for the dot size and get something like this
[dot plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdcMD.png) (please note, in the picture the y axis is reversed, the lables should be 3>1, 2=2 and 1>3)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:?

```
df=read.table(text="
       A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
     1   1   3   1   5   5
     2   1   3   2   6   9
     3   2   1   3   8   11
     4   2   1   4   9   15",header=T)

ggplot(gather(df[,4:6]),aes(x=key,y=value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=gather(df[,1:3])$value)) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: Perfect, it is what I was looking for.